# Code Coverage tool for Html5

Tags: html, code-coverage

Is there a code coverage tool that can be used for Html5?

I came across a tool for Javascript (JSCoverage) but i dont see any reference to if it can be used for Html5?

I see another tool called Clover. can that be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is not a programming language; it's just the markup language and a set of APIs. A JavaScript code coverage tool should be independent of what version of HTML you are using. So whether JSCoverage works for you shouldn't depend on whether you're using HTML5 or not; it should just depend on whether JSCoverage works with your codebase.

When many people say "HTML5" they mean HTML5 + JavaScript + CSS. If that's what you mean, then yes, JSCoverage should work for you.

It looks like [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/) has been superseded by [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/), so you might want to try that instead.

Clover is a Java code coverage tool, not JavaScript (despite the similarity in name, they have nothing to do with one another). Clover will not work for an HTML5 + JavaScript + CSS application.